# Burninate [general-health]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[general-health](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-health) is not a good tag at all. It could literally be used on every question on this site, which is not a good thing. From the [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) page in the help center:

> Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.

[general-health](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-health) is just too broad of a tag to narrow questions into categories that can be easily found.

Let's burninate it!

**Update 9/22/2015**: This is now burninated. Please ping a mod in chat or comment here if you see it recurring.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with this. Three additional notes:

1. The main problem with having [general-health](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-health), in my view, is that it potentially distracts from other relevant and specific tags that would be more helpful for site organization. If users find the [general-health](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-health) tag and are satisfied, they may not expend the energy to think about what the question is *really* about.
2. Some questions such as [this one](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/787/165) are difficult to categorize in our current tagging system apart from [general-health](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-health). My own opinion is that we’d be better off creating tags such as [health-literacy](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-literacy) and possibly others in the “meta-health” category if such questions are indeed on topic. (I think they should be.)
3. Because it’s likely to pop up again shortly after burnination, I suggest that it should also be [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/272257).

Comment: +1, but I would advise against "health-literacy", as it sounds so generic, it will be misused by people who don't know of this discussion. We need something which, when seen on a list, does *not* sound like it fits mostly any question.

Comment: Any ideas for a good tag for questions like the linked one? Of course, I intended it to be for questions *about* health literacy rather than *in the interest of* health literacy, the latter being applicable to every question on the site.  But I see what you mean about possible misuses.

Comment: I don't have an overview of all questions tagged with general-health, but my suspicion is, if we are closing it as too general, there is no single tag to cover all of them. For the one question you gave as an example, we can have a tag like [information-source-recommendation]. This is somewhat thorny, as many sites on the network don't allow this question, mainly because once there are 3-4 competing resources, voting does not pick the best one. But there are precedents for sites which allow it, e.g. biology, so we can try too.

Comment: Other questions will have to be retagged individually. Here is something I learned from other site definition phases: if you cannot create a tag which fits a question, this is a good sign the question is off topic and should be closed anyway.